# Clearing all files from a Liquidsoap equeue, to schedule playlists

Tags: python, telnet, liquidsoap

I'm using an `equeue` to play a playlist by pushing tracks into it. Let's say, after an hour a new playlist (set of files) is pushed to the queue. Unfortunately these tracks don't start playing, because they are queued **after** the previously queued files.

Following script removes the files from the queue:

```
input_fs = request.equeue(id="fs")

def clear_items(s) =
    ret = server.execute("fs.primary_queue")
    ret = list.hd(ret)
    if ret == "" then
        log("Queue cleared.")
        (-1.)
    else
        log("There are still items in the queue, trying skip ...")
        source.skip(s)
        (0.1)
    end
end

def clear_queue(s) =
    add_timeout(fast=false, 0.5, {clear_items(s)})
end

server.register(namespace="fs",
    description="Clear the all items of the filesystem queue.",
    usage="clear",
    "clear",
    fun (s) -> begin clear_queue(input_fs) "Done." end)
```

It works when called via Telnet, but also adds some additional timeout. As a consequence the scheduling for the next playlist is delayed somewhat.

Note, I'm performing LiquidSoap scheduling via an Python application, which pushes to the queue using timed threads.

What would you say is the recommended way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by introducing two filesystem queues A and B.

1. **Queue A** is populated with playlist items and played
2. After some time the **Queue B** is also populated, but not yet played.
3. As soon the playout transitioned to **Queue B** and started playing, there's plenty of time to clear anything left in **Queue A**